# ¿Cómo crear un contenedor en docker que contenga el frontend y el backend de un proyecto con laravel (backend) y angular (frontend)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hola quiero crear un contenedor en docker con la siguiente estructura:

```
Directorio Principal del Contenedor
   -backend (LAMP Stack + laravel 7)
   -frontend (MEAN Stack con Angular 9 + MySQL)
   -docker
       -php
           -php.ini
       -apache
          -apache2.conf
          -vhost.conf
```

Con una imagen de base de datos MySQL que se pueda compartir con varios contenedores.

Tengo creado un contenedor con LAMP Stack y una imagen de composer funcional, pero no sé cómo hacer funcionar laravel dentro del contenedor.

A continuación muestro el código funcional que tengo del Dockerfile y docker-compose:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
LABEL maintainer="ruben"
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        vim \
        curl \
        git \
        supervisor \
        zip \
        unzip \
        && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip intl xmlrpc soap opcache \
        && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -- \
        && apt-get install -y nodejs \
        && apt-get autoremove -y

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
#COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
#COPY docker/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
#COPY docker/apache/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Suppress the do-not-run-as-root warning from composer
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        image: lamp-img
        container_name: lamp-cont
        build: ./
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "81:80"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
    myadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        ports:
            - "82:80"
        links:
            - mysql:db
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:8.0
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "83:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_HOST: 0.0.0.0
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: v4n3rub3
volumes:
    mysql:
        driver: "local"
```

De antemano agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan dar

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Donde está la descarga del código de Laravel? Y luego el composer install? Es decir veo mucha infraestructura para el proyecto de Laravel pero por ningún lado nada de Laravel en sí.

Comment: Hola Jesús. Precisamente eso es lo que quiero añadir en la carpeta del backend. ¿Cómo uso el composer para instalar laravel? dentro del Dockerfil o dentro del docker-compose.yml?? PD:Tengo una imagen de composer instalada en mi docker.

Comment: Nunca lo he usado con docker compose y PHP pero lo que he visto y usado con proyectos de Node es instalar paquetería en el dockerfile.